# generate Typescript `d.ts` file from swagger yml file

Tags: typescript, swagger, next.js

I'm using `dtsgenerator` to generate type for my `Nextjs` project from a Rest Api but it generate all the name camel case. But I want them to be uppercase and separated with `_`. Is there any Idea?

I write a code to read the `d.ts` generated by `dtsgenerator` and change the name is there better and faster way?

Comment: Putting TypeScript aside, JavaScript does not have a naming convention including underscores. If you can, stick with camelCase (or PascalCase in some parts). Plus, you have more than one question indeed; maybe peek at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @vahdet in this way my variable definition and type are the same one the best convention is to define the types in uppercase.